# C++ See If Argument Is Numeric

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, numeric

I'm creating an encryption/decryption program in C++, and I use three user-provided numbers to customize the encryption. I read about isdigit() on cplusplus.com, and made a function based on that:

```
bool is_numeric(char *string)
{
    int sizeOfString = sizeof(string);
    int iteration = 0;
    bool isNumeric = true;

    while(iteration < sizeOfString)
    {
        if(!isdigit(string[iteration]))
        {
            isNumeric = false;
            break;
        }

        iteration++;

    }

    return isNumeric;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. Whether I give it a number, or a non-numeric character, it still returns false. What is wrong with my approach.

Comment: It is a bit dangerous to call your string string. If you use the std then you may hit some problems, especially if you are using namespace std.

Comment: I don't use `use namespace std`. I always use `std::whatever`, which seems to be the correct way to do things.

Comment: sizeof returns the compile time size of the type that it is called on. The string variable has type `char *`, so you are getting the size of a `char *` variable. Note that with C arrays the type of the array is also its size. E.G. the type of `int foo[100]` is an array of 100 ints. Note that there is a gotcha where these arrays silently decay to a pointer in many circumstances. http://ideone.com/gYqUiY might be useful.

Comment: You could also use [strspn](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strspn/) and check if its returned value is `strlen(string)`. This collapses your function into a single line, and additionally you could add other characters when desired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are computing the `sizeOfString` wrong.  Try this instead.

```
bool is_numeric(char *string)
{
    int sizeOfString = strlen(string);
    int iteration = 0;
    bool isNumeric = true;

    while(iteration < sizeOfString)
    {
        if(!isdigit(string[iteration]))
        {
            isNumeric = false;
            break;
        }

        iteration++;

    }

    return isNumeric;
}
```

You may want to add functionality to check for the `.` character as well!  Right now your code only returns true if your string is an integer.

Comment: That certainly fixed it. Thanks for fixing my stupid mistake.

Comment: Also consider using a `for`-loop to make your code more readable. Also, `i` is often used for a simple iteration variable: `for(int i=0; i<sizeOfString; i++){/*your code*/}`

Comment: @JerryCoffin that is because `À` has a value of `192` making it part of **the extended ASCII codes**.  Which is beyond the limits of a `char` [max: 127].

Comment: @KirkBackus: It's a reasonable (and, in some parts of the world, common) character. No, it's not defined by ASCII, but nobody's used ASCII in decades.

Comment: @JerryCoffin `ASCII` is a very old standard, but anybody that is using `char` is limited to `ASCII` characters.  Since `UTF-8` is fully backward compatible with `ASCII`, technically everybody is using `ASCII` (when the first bit is 0).

Comment: @KirkBackus: You're still left with the fact that what's being passed is a `char`, and (with the usual implementation of `char`) *half* the values that can be passed in a char will lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Even if the data-type was changed to `unsigned char`, doing this: `is_numeric("算");` -> crash.  Granted, `is_numeric("À");` would have worked fine, but the code using `char` is simply a design choice.  There is nothing inherently wrong with using `char` for strings, after all, it may not be necessary to use anything bigger.

Comment: @KirkBackus: Sorry, but wrong. Passing and unsigned char won't crash for any value of `char`. "算" will be encoded in *some* narrow encoding (up to the implementation) which will be fine. You're probably thinking of L"算", but that will be a `wchar_t *`, not `char *`.

Answer (score 5):

I think I'd use a standard algorithm:

```
bool is_numeric(char const *string)
{
    return std::all_of(string, string+strlen(string), 
                       [](unsigned char c) { return ::isdigit(c); });
}
```

Note that as it stands, your code can (often will) have undefined behavior (if the string contains anything that works out as a negative number when encoded into a char). This code prevents that by converting the `char` to an `unsigned char` as it's passed to the lambda -- that's why I used a lambda instead of just passing `::isdigit` as the predicate to `all_of`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ('0' <= *string && *string <= '9')
    ++string;
return *string == '\0';
```

or, if you prefer using `isdigit`:

```
while (is digit((int)*string))
    ++string;
return *string == '\0';
```

Comment: You really want to cast to `unsigned char`, not `int`. Promotion from `char` to `int` happens automatically, but a negative input will remain negative, so you still get undefined behavior.

Comment: @JerryCoffin - yup, too hasty.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is using a stringstream:

```
bool isNumeric(const string& s) {
    stringstream ss(s);
    int val;
    ss >> val;
    return ! ss.fail() && ss.eof();
}
```

stringstream::operator>>(int&) will make the stringstream's failbit to be set if the given string is not numeric, and you need to check if all that's in the string is exactly one integer (and nothing else), so you also test for the eof bit. 
This also works for negative numbers, and you can also change the int to double if you want to accept floating point numbers.